# ASP.NET MVC and JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, multidimensional-array

I want to post a two dimensional array to an ASP.NET MVC controller but it is always null and I do not find the error, please:
The array from Firefox:

```
ch  […]
0   AAA
1   BBB
2   CCC
customerName    MMMMM NNNN
ids […]
0   []
1   […]
0   146
1   156
2   179
3   182
4   188
2   […]
0   5184
3   […]
0   3e19b070-ea48-dd11-ad5c-000f1fffae55
1   2249a492-677e-e611-9433-00155d109841
4   []
5   []
```

JavaScript:

```
var temp = [];
for (var is = 1; is < data[i].Rows.length; is++) {
   temp.push(data[i].Rows[is][0]);
}
json.push(temp);
```

Ajax POST:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data: JSON.stringify({ 'ids': json, 'ch': ch, 'customerName': $('#name').val() }),
dataType: "json",
```

ASP.NET MVC controller head:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(string[][] ids, string[] ch, string customerName)
```

Please.

**UPDATE:**

```
if (data[i].Rows.length > 1) {
  var temp = [];
  for (var is = 1; is < data[i].Rows.length; is++) {
    temp.push(data[i].Rows[is][0]);
  }
  json.push(temp);
}
```

I do not push empty arrays into json array and it works.

Comment: Passing multidimensional/jagged array like that should be avoided. Better to create a viewmodel class that contains properties you want to pass as an array for controller action, `push` it with values and use it as `data` option AJAX call (remember to set `traditional: true`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, i noticed that may array contains both int and string but when I put them between quotation marks: temp.push("'" + data[i].Rows[is][0] + "'"); it is also null in Action method. ThenI have put them in a VM but null again. Somewhere I do it wrong.

Comment: The JavaScript array is wrong because when it send this: [['a', 'b', 'c', 'z'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'y']] everything is OK.